# Improve texture resolution in GLSL fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, textures, webgl, shader

Is there a way to icrease, or improve resolution of a texture using GLSL fragment shader processing? Let's say, I have 512x424 px source image, and want to have 1024x848 px as a result, with smooth pixels.

Update.
Under "improvement" I mean enlarging using some sort of resampling algorithm.

Comment: By "Improve texture" and "smooth pixels", do you mean upscaling with interpolation?

Comment: @gre_gor I mean enlarging using some sort of resampling algorithm, e.g. "bicubic smoother" resampling in Photoshop.

Comment: Have you used glTexParameter to set the minification and magnification filters? GL_NEAREST and GL_LINEAR can be set...

Comment: @WLGfx I'm setting GL_LINEAR interpolation. However that's not exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for unclear request. Finally I found what answers my question: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/236394/bi-cubic-and-bi-linear-interpolation-with-glsl (Zoom An Image With Different Interpolation Types)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create FBO, attach large destination texture with desired dimensions
2. Render "full-screen" textured quad with small source texture bound

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did what you suggested (by the means of three.js).   And applied Bi-Cubic Triangular interpolation. This article describes what I was looking for: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/236394/bi-cubic-and-bi-linear-interpolation-with-glsl (Zoom An Image With Different Interpolation Types). Sorry for unclear request.